# How can I get started with developing on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, development

Is there any tutorial on how can we build, debug or add features on PostgreSQL database source code, or even develop and debug extensions?

I am interest on adding some features on PostgreSQL database logical replication, I have a few years to write C++, so I need a warm up.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone/fork the code from the [official Github-Mirror](https://github.com/postgres/postgres). There even is a tutorial on the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/git.html) by PostgreSQL.

As for the development itself, there is a rather extensive [Developer FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ) that should cover most things. Some experts from the FAQ:

> PostgreSQL is developed mostly in the C programming language.

> The complete list of required software to build PostgreSQL can be found in the [installation instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-requirements.html).

> You really should have an editor that can handle tags.

For more detailed explanation, you can also see [Part IV](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-interfaces.html) and [Part V](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-programming.html) of the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html), which deal with client- and server-side programming respectively. For more explicit questions, the [pgsql-hackers-archive](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/) would be useful, as Laurenz Albe pointet out.

Comment: Developer FAQ are not extensive as they do not provide start-to-end examples or how to debug new developed code. Forking the code doesn't mean you can built it, it just stay on your repo.

Comment: You cannot expect to be spoon-fed. The answer is good. Perhaps you should start by lurking on pgsql-hackers and reviewing patches during commitfests.

Comment: I do not except that but coming to an already existing product developed from lot of people with high skill set, I believe it would be nice to have more detailed trainings, maybe online to make learning curve worth it, at least for new people (my opinion). A good example would be to have an overview over the files into GitRepository, comments are not enough.